# Single word request for varying temporal trends

Tags: single-word-requests

Please help to find a correct adjective for summing up varying 9-year temporal trends.

I examined 9-year temporal trends of certain patients' care. For assessing these trends, multiple indicators had to be measured. The results showed varied trends:

1. we detected increased access to services (**a positive thing**) but half still had no access at the end of the observed period (**the change was clearly insufficient**);
2. inequality in the division of health care resources increased (**a negative thing**);
3. regional disparities persisted or even increased (**both are negative things**).

Thus, we found one small positive trend and multiple negative ones. The situation is clearly worrisome and urgent improvements are needed. What would be a good adjective for describing such trends?

> Diverse temporal trends

> Varying temporal trends

> Omnidirectional temporal trends

Comment: Could you explain why you are using the adjective "temporal"? There appears to be no reference to time.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the OP - we analysed 9-year trends.

Comment: This merely makes it worse: it is now tautologous. The use of the adjectival phrase "9-year" has to be "concerned with time". Therefore "temporal" should not be there. *I examined 9-year temporal trends of certain patients' care.* should be *I examined the trends in certain patients' care over a period of nine years.*

Comment: 'We carried out research over 9 years to investigate how ... varied over time.'

Comment: If you want to emphasize that they are generally negative, why not "generally adverse".  If you want to emphasize that there are some positives mixed in, then "inconclusive".  If I am headed in the right direction I'll make this into an answer.

Comment: Sometimes, when the correlation between two things is that each goes in opposing directions, it is described as *inversely related*.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - It’s more likely that “We analyzed 9 years of data to investigate how … varied over time.”

Comment: Trends *are* temporal, so *9-year trends*. The trends are mostly negative.

Comment: "*mixed bag* of trends" is hard to improve upon for brevity.  Maybe "both positive and negative trends."